# Añadir campo dentro de un Objeto dentro de un Array

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs

Tengo un servidor montado en Node.js mediante el cual realizo una consulta y esta me devuelve un JSON, dentro de este tiene un Array de objetos. Lo que quiero hacer es insertar un valor extra dentro de uno de los objetos. Este es el código que mantengo.

```
sql.connect(config, function (err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        var request = new sql.Request();
        console.log(req.query)
        var qry = 'SELECT * FROM (select i.nombre_insumo,i.IDINS,c.cantidad,c.lote_proveedor,c.fecha_vencimiento,c.Bodega from C_APP_REGISTROS c inner join C_APP_INSUMOS i on c.id_insumo = i.IDINS WHERE IDREG = '+idreg+' UNION ALL SELECT NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL) X'


        request.query(qry , function (err, rows) {
            if(!err){
                bodega = rows['recordsets'][0][0]['Bodega']
                idins = rows['recordsets'][0][0]['IDINS']
                console.log(bodega)
                if(bodega!="LN"){
                    res.send(rows['recordsets'][0]);
                }else{
                    enviarConsulta()
                }
                console.log("-------------------------------xD")
            } else{
                res.send(err)
            }
        });
    });
```

Mi idea es que dentro del IF se envie un dato extra, ademas de todos los que se obtuvieron en la consulta. He intentado lo siguiente.

```
 if(bodega!="LN"){
     rows['recordsets'][0].push({Stock:123})
     res.send(rows['recordsets'][0]);
 }else{
     enviarConsulta()
 }
```

Pero obtengo otro objeto dentro del array y mi idea es que se encuentre dentro del primer objeto.

```
        [
  {
"nombre_insumo": "CALDO SX2 - CJ.20 TUBOS (42121)",
"IDINS": 79,
"cantidad": "25/50",
"lote_proveedor": "1728030",
"fecha_vencimiento": "2020-06-02T00:00:00.000Z",
"Bodega": "CF"
"Stock":"123"
},
  {
"nombre_insumo": null,
"IDINS": null,
"cantidad": null,
"lote_proveedor": null,
"fecha_vencimiento": null,
"Bodega": null
},   

 {
 "Stock":"123" 
}

],
```

la idea final es que el

> "Stock" : 123

quede tal que asi:

```
[
  {
"nombre_insumo": "CALDO SX2 - CJ.20 TUBOS (42121)",
"IDINS": 79,
"cantidad": "25/50",
"lote_proveedor": "1728030",
"fecha_vencimiento": "2020-06-02T00:00:00.000Z",
"Bodega": "CF"
"Stock":"123"
},
  {
"nombre_insumo": null,
"IDINS": null,
"cantidad": null,
"lote_proveedor": null,
"fecha_vencimiento": null,
"Bodega": null
}
],
```

Espero se entienda la pregunta :C

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Espero que ésto te ayude:

```
    rows['recordsets'][0]['Stock']=123
```

Comment: Wow, eran tan simple la respueta :C , muchas gracias

Comment: Hola anacleto, aunque esta respuesta puede servir para resolver el problema, ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad. Las publicaciones que son básicamente código se consideran de baja calidad y no suelen ser de ayuda para otros usuarios. Por favor, añade algo más de detalle: ¿qué hace esa línea de código? ¿dónde iría en el código de la pregunta? ¿qué hace o cómo soluciona el problema? Lee [answer] y completa el [tour] para más información.

Comment: HAHAHA I'm a fool, if what you said worked. Thank you!